# How to and when to check the validity of token

Tags: android, github, oauth

I am developing an app of github.And I come across some problem of token/auth2.

I use AccountMannager to handle the account/password/token locally.

1. First time to login,Create token and save locally
2. After first time,I get token locally to request the resource from remote server

And I don't know if I need to check the validity of token every time I try to use local token to send https request.

If I have to check the validity of token every time.It seems meaningless that I save the token locally,Why don't I get a token from remote server every time.

Answer (score 0):

You should not check the token. By sending invalid token to the server (e.g expired one) the server answers with 401 unauthorized code and your app should trigger regeneration of the token.